# replacing special placeholders in HTML file with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, markers

Good day to everybody!

I have this sort of HTML file:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>First name: </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p> %first_name% </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Last name: </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p"> %last_name% </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I'm looking for a way of replacing special markers of type(%smth%) by concrete data. Project's being developed under Qt, so I wonder if some Qt's methods can do it.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you tied to the `% %` format? Because the native way is `& ;` named entities.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution might be using [QString & **QString::replace** ( const QString & before, const QString & after, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qstring.html#replace-8) which replaces every occurrence of the string *before* with the string *after* and returns a reference to this string.

Place the contents of your html file into a QString then call QString::replace() to replace the special markers by concrete data. For example:

```
QString firstName("John");
html.replace("%first_name%", firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as [you can not use regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I recommend using
 XSLT which supported by [xmlpatterns](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtxmlpatterns-module.html) library.

**EDIT**

As someone thinks he still can parse html with regexp in this case, I will give some examples, that will show regexps fail:

1. You have marker in attribute (and you don't want it to be replaced)

   ```
   <p class="%first name">
   ```
2. Someone would deside to inject:

   ```
   map: %firstname -> <srcipt language ="javascript">....</script>
   ```

   After XSLT substitution will be escaped automatically.

Comment: Why would he need to match tags? He doesn't need XPath-like functionality.